# First and Second touch of a button, how to show images at different times?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad, touch

I want to change the css of an image after touching a button and I want to change the css of another image after touching the button for a second time.

How can I combine this code in 1 function? Because now when I touch the button it shows me the 2 images at the same time.

```
$('.button').on('touchend', function(){
   $('img.image1').css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$('.button').on('touchend', function(){
   $('img.image2').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this ? You just need a flag to know how many time the button is pressed or touched.

```
var timeTouched = 0;

$('.button').on('touchend', function(){
   if (timeTouched == 0){
      $('img.image1').css('visibility', 'visible');
   }
   else {
      $('img.image2').css('visibility', 'visible');
   }
   timeTouched++;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a flag or something like this to change the button binding every time it is clicked.

```
var action = 1;
$("input").on("click", viewSomething);

function viewSomething() {
    if ( action == 1 ) {
        $("body").css("background", "honeydew");
        action = 2;
    } else {
        $("body").css("background", "beige");
        action = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

will first turn on img 1 and then on second click turn on img 2.  This does not hide either but just add the css to img 1 first then on second click add the css to img 2.

```
$('.button').on('touchend', function(){
   if($('img.image1').css('visibility') == 'visible')
   {
     $('img.image2').css('visibility', 'visible');
   }
   else
   {
     $('img.image1').css('visibility', 'visible');
   }
});
```